# iphone Database update Issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am working on iPhone app and  calling following code on my button click, its updating my Database table only on first click. When I click it second time it gives me success message but database table is not getting updated.

Code is :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Games.sqlite"];

NSMutableArray *arrayRandomLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];
for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % 5;
    [arrayRandomLevel  exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    //firstObject +=1;       
}
NSLog(@"arrayRandomLevel = %@",arrayRandomLevel);

for (int level = 0; level < 5; level++)
{
    NSString *strLevel = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",level+1];
    int finalLevel = [[arrayRandomLevel objectAtIndex:level] intValue];

    NSLog(@"Static level = %@, Changed level = %d",strLevel,finalLevel);

    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE zquestionsdata SET zdifficultylevel = %d WHERE zanswertype = '%@' AND zquestiontype = '%@';",finalLevel,strLevel,@"Geni"];

        const char * sql = [cmd UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_step(compiledStatement); // Here is the added step.
            NSLog(@"update SUCCESS - executed command %@",cmd);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"update FAILED - failed to execute command %@",cmd);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"pdateContact FAILED - failed to open database");
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Please help me on this or provide any other solution to update table each time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: nslog your NSString *cmd, copy the message from console then try to paste it on your sqlite database browser to test the query

Comment: in this line zquestiontype = '%@';"    , I dont think you need a semicolon there

Comment: I copy cmd and try to run on sqlite browser, its working there and updating tables rows. but not through my function.

Answer (score 1):

The Updating process will happen at

> if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)

There the values assigned will go and store in the database the statement look like the above.

code from Prepare statement is given below

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)   
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
          //assign new values here

         }
     }
```

Comment: its working on first time as usual, from second click its coming inside   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) block but table is not getting updated with this. Showing old results. I want to update it on 2nd, 3rd and so on click